# Getters e Setters só podem "andar" juntos?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, getters-setters

Estou estudando orientação a objetos e estou tendo algumas dúvidas na parte de encapsulamento. Por exemplo:

```
Class Url {

    private $url;

    public function setUrl($url) {

        if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            $this -> url = $url;
        } else {
            $this->url= false;
        }
    }

    public function getUrl(){

        return $this->url;

    }


}
```

Como eu preciso validar o URL eu criei este *setter*, já que é uma melhor prática do que fazer a validação no construtor, correto?

Usarei ele fora da classe, mas esse *getter* não, então preciso mesmo criar ambos? Por que eu poderia usar a variável `$url` no contexto da classe, já que só usarei ela dentro da classe mesmo.

Aproveitando essa pergunta, entendi que eu só criaria o *setter*/*getter* se eu fosse alterar o valor da variável ao longo da aplicação, correto? Caso contrário eu poderia simplesmente "construí-la" no construtor? Exemplo:

```
public function __construct ($url) {

    $this->url = $url;

}
```

Comment: Melhorei a redação da pergunta mas vale a pena você dar uma revisada pois numa parte você diz que vai usar o valor fora da classe e noutro momento você afirma que não vai precisar do *getter* porque o valor só vai ser usado dentro da classe. Não mexi nessa parte (para adicionar um **não** à primeira declaração), para não radicalizar sua intenção.

Comment: Eu quis dizer que usarei o setter fora da classe, mas poderia usar diretamente a variável $url, sem o getter, entendeu?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Em Orientação a Objetos *getters* e *setters* participam do **Princípio da Ocultação de Informação**, o qual garante que uma propriedade esteja disponível para leitura ou gravação apenas em determinadas circunstâncias:

- **Private:** Apenas quem definiu
- **Protected:** Quem definiu e quem dele estender
- **Public:** Todo mundo

Porém, tanto *getters* quanto *setters* são opcionais. E isso permite que você simule propriedades somente-leitura e até mesmo somente-escrita (se é que existe alguma aplicação prática pra isso) o que, até o presente momento, não podem ser feitos automaticamente a nível de interpretação:

No seu exemplo, definir visibilidade da propriedade *Url::$url* como **private** garante que ninguém possa alterar seu valor diretamente.

Se ela tivesse visibilidade **public**, isso poderia ocorrer:

```
$url = new Url;

$url -> url = 'Oi, eu sou Goku!';
```

E qualquer coisa que dependa de uma URL válida, falharia.

Sendo assim, você tem como garantir que apenas URLs sejam informadas como valor para esse argumento pois através de um *setter*, você pode validar.

Se esse valor precisar ser lido no contexto da instância, você deve adicionar um *getter*. Mas se esse argumento não puder ser **alterado** no mesmo contexto, você **não precisa** e nem deve ter um *setter* pois uma vez definida a URL ela deve ser mantida a mesma até o objeto ser destruído manualmente ou ao fim da Requisição.

Porém, apesar de o construtor de um objeto servir para construir o objeto (doh) ele não deve fazer tudo sozinho.

O ideal é delegar a tarefa de validação e atribuição do valor à propriedade através de um *setter*.

*Mas você está se contradizendo!*

Sim, pode parecer isso, mas assim como propriedades têm visibilidade configuráveis, assim são para com os métodos, então você pode sim ter um método especificamente criado para validar e setar um valor à essa propriedade, mas que não esteja disponível externamente:

```
class Url {

    private $url;

    public function __construct( $url ) {

        $this -> setUrl( $url );
    }

    private function setUrl( $url ) {

        if( filter_var( $url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) === FALSE ) {

            throw new InvalidArgumentException(

                sprintf( '%s is not a valid URL', $url )
            );
        }

        $this -> url= $url;
    }

    public function getUrl(){
        return $this -> url;
    }
}
```

Perceba, também, a diferença nesse código em relação ao seu. Você **aceita** uma URL inválida o que te força a verificar manualmente se esse valor é uma URL válida quando sua classe precisar usar o valor dessa propriedade, de novo, de novo e de novo.

E isso derrota o propósito de um *setter* que é justamente garantir que a informação passada seja confiável.

Nesse exemplo, se a URL não passar na validação eu disparo uma [InvalidArgumentException](http://php.net/InvalidArgumentException), uma Exceção nativamente disponível específica para ser usada quando um dado argumento for inválido para o propósito de quem o definiu.

Bons estudos :)

Comment: Obrigado, Muito boa a resposta, consegui pegar a ideia :)

Comment: Só um avisinho rs, o Sprintf não funciona porque você atribuiu à variável false, então não mostra a URL, mas já corrigi, Muito Obrigado :))

Answer (score 12):

Não, você pode usar qualquer um dos dois isoladamente conforme sua necessidade. A boa prática é aquele que você precisa e está correta.

Se você não vai usar o *getter* publicamente, não o crie.

De fato se você também não precisa atribuir valor para uma propriedade publicamente, o que faz bastante sentido se não vai ter um *getter*, então também não tem porque criar um *setter*. Se precisa apenas inicializar um membro da classe, e eventualmente validar, faça no construtor.

```
Class Url {
    private $url;

    public function __construct ($url) {
        if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            $this -> url = $url;
        } else {
            $this->url= false;
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/NoGetterSetter.php).

Claro que depende de como você quer usar esta variável de instância `$url`. Eu imagino que tudo o que for manipulá-la dentro da classe não dependa da validação colocada no construtor, caso contrário seria interessante usar um método que sirva de intermediário para acessar a variável. Em geral você pode controlar o estado dela de forma mais confiável dentro da classe e não precisa da validação.

Comment: Entendi, mas fiquei um pouco confuso da explicação no final, se eu já a validei no construtor porque eu precisaria ter que criar um método para tal? então, não seria melhor criar logo o setter/getter para usar dentro da classe? Obrigado!

Comment: Exatamente, não costuma fazer sentido ter estes métodos no caso que você está demonstrando. O que poderia acontecer em um caso hipotético de uma classe complexa que fica manipulando algum dado e correndo o risco de colocá-la em estado inválido. Aí poderia ser interessante ter uma método que intermediasse isto para validar toda vez que ele é alterado. Mas tenha isto como algo raro. Este método seria o *setter*.