# Como modificar ou setar um valor dentro do class no php

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Tenho uma `class` no `php` e preciso modificar o valor de `private $key = "valor";` fora da `class`.

Como posso modificar o valor de `$key` fora dessa classe? O valor que quero colocar em `$key` vem de um `$_POST["name"]`.

```
class Webcmd {
    private $key = "valor padrão a ser modificado";
    function __construct(){}
    ...
}
```

Não consegui achar uma maneira de definir esse valor fora do `class Webcmd` e agora também não consigo *setar* um valor que esta sendo passado via `POST`.

**Como posso fazer isso?**

Comment: Tentou criar um setter?

Comment: Não, não costumo usar `class`. Tentei umas "coisas" que encontrei pesquisando, mas nenhuma deu certo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para alterar o estado de algum atributo de uma classe é comum criar métodos acessores `get` para leitura e `set` para escrita, dessa forma é possível centralizar algumas validações simples.

Caso esse valor não precise ser alterado pode trocar o setter por um parâmetro no construtor.

```
<?php

class Webcmd {
    private $key = "valor padrão a ser modificado";
    function __construct() {
    }

    public function getKey() {
        return $this->key;
    }

    public function setKey($key) {
        $this->key = $key;
    }

}

//chamada
$web = new Webcmd();
$web->setKey('Novo valor');
echo $web->getKey();
```

**Relacionado:**

[Quando usar Setters e Getters?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43757/91)

[Getters e Setters só podem “andar” juntos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44739/91)

[Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/91)

Comment: Deu certo, não sabia que dava pra fazer isso.