# É realmente necessário usar métodos para mutator e acessor (setter e getter) no PHP? E o desempenho?

Tags: php, desempenho, design-pattern, estilo-de-codificação, getters-setters

Venho percebendo que a maioria de outras bibliotecas utilizam os métodos *setters* e *getters*  (doravante denominados de *mutator* e *accessor*), para alterar a propriedade de algumas classe.

Por exemplo:

```
class User
{
    protected $name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Esse é um exemplo clássico. Eu tenho uma classe que representa o usuário, e a mesma possui uma propriedade chamada `name`, que representa o nome do usuário. Para alterar o valor de `name`, precisamo usar `User::setName`, e para obtê-lo, `User::getName`.

Por um lado podemos pensar que seria mais simples fazer algo como:

```
$user = new User;

$user->name = 'Wallace';
```

Concordo que essa maneira seria a mais simples. Porém há casos onde eu reconheço que é necessária a criação de uma forma de validar como esse nome pode ser inserido ou tipo da variável.

Exemplo:

```
public function setName($name)

{
    if (is_string($name) && count(explode(' ', $name)) >= 2))
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Name is not valid');
}
```

Olhando por esse lado (e sempre só olho por esse lado), percebo que é útil usar *mutators* por conta de poder validar os dados que vão ser definidos num determinado objeto (como validação de tipos, ou validações especificas para um atributo).

Outro detalhe é que, se você estiver [programando para interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86484/programar-voltado-para-interface-e-n%C3%A3o-para-a-implementa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-por-que), a mesma no PHP não aceita a definição de propriedades obrigatórias num objeto, e sim somente métodos e constantes.

Mas algumas questões que sempre me veem à cabeça é como a de um amigo meu que disse: "PHP não é Java, não é necessário fazer tais coisas".

Então vai aqui algumas questões sobre isso:

Já ouvi também alguns boatos de que **encher uma classe de métodos pode reduzir a performance**.

Outro detalhe também é que vejo implementações de *mutator/acessor* com o uso de métodos mágicos `__isset`, `__get` e `__set`, ou ainda `__call` e `__callStatic`. Alguns dizem que também há uma questão de redução de desempenho quando os usamos.

Sendo assim:

- Quando eu deveria usar ou não *mutator/accessor* numa classe? Essa forma é utilizada visando padronizar o código, ou visando uma implementação, ou é apenas para imitar o Java? (o último comentário realmente eu já ouvi)
- Existe algum caso (real) que eu não precise utilizar (com exemplo, por favor, pois não consigo visualizar, por conta do que citei sobre validações ou possíveis validações futuras)?
- Por que as bibliotecas escrita em PHP (e as "pessoas") gostam mais de usar *mutator/accessor* do que em definir uma propriedade pública para uma classe e defini-la "externamente"?

Comment: O que achas dessas? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44739/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43757/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33723/101,

Comment: Obrigado Mr @bigown. Agora percebo que a maioria não chama de "mutator/accessor". Pode fechar ;)

Comment: Ou melhor, não fecha ainda. Essa aqui tem citações sobre desempenho, talvez alguém tenha algo a dizer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O principal motivo para usar métodos *getter* e *setter* é ter algo além de um simples acesso e atribuição na propriedade.

Então se não tiver um processamento, não deve usar? Não é isso, pode ser interessante usar sim, e aí responde a última questão. É a velha resposta da abstração. Quando faz isto fica garantido que pode trocar a implementação do acesso/atribuição quando quiser. Pode por ou tirar processamento, afinal o acesso sempre será feito pelo método. Se deixar o acesso direto pela variável, não pode trocar isto sem afetar o código que consomem a propriedade.

Afinal [não existe problema na computação que não possa ser resolvido com um nível extra de indireção](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering). ([O que é indireção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101))

Também é interessante para o caso citado da interface. Aliás esse é o motivo de existir interface, abstrair a implementação.

Então não é só para imitar o Java, se vai imitar código do Java, mas pode não usar nada disto se preferir escrever código normal de PHP.

Precisar usar? Não precisa, ele pode facilitar a manutenção futura. Se tiver um caso onde seja certo que a implementação não pode ser trocada, não precisa usar nunca.

Certamente há um custo maior em chamar um método, mas já sabe, em PHP a diferença é pequena. Tem que medir para ver se está atrapalhando.

Aconselho ler [Métodos Getters e Setters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101) e todos os *links* constantes lá antes de começar usar esse recurso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O único caso onde vi um framework deixando uma propriedade como `public` foi no laravel, que é uma propriedade que recebe `true` ou `false`. Aí faz sentido não ter que usar método (apesar de alguns que fariam questão de criar um setter para boolean) :D

Comment: Não sei. Depende. Pode ser gambi. Não tenho como saber. Só perguntando para quem fez.

Answer (score 12):

Getters e Setters não foram criados em Java, mas foram popularizados por ela, o uso obrigatório deles faz parte da cultura de hiper abstração da linguagem onde você nunca pode escrever algo que apenas funcione, tem que ter vários níveis de abstração, vários métodos que não fazem nada além de inflar a quantidade de linhas de código para que você possa sentir que está programando como um rock star enquanto digita furiosamente aqueles 10 getters e setters, que sua IDE gera automaticamente mas você gosta de fazer na mão para deixar transeuntes boquiabertos com suas habilidades de codificação .

Zoeiras a parte o motivo do uso você já conhece, você cria métodos de acesso para a propriedade para que caso queira fazer algum processamento antes de recuperar elas (getter) e antes de armazenar-las (setter), isso é definitivamente muito útil...quando faz sentido. O que ocorre na prática é você ver várias classes com dezenas de getters/setters que não fazem nada e nunca vão fazer, afinal talvez você nunca precise processar o atributo na hora de recuperar ou de setar ou ainda isso pode ser tranquilamente feito no construtor, então no fim isso é um padrão que a maioria usa sem pensar nem contestar, não que seja necessariamente ruim.

Quanto a performance existe sim um overhead afinal você troca o acesso direto do atributo pela chamada de um método que faz o acesso, ainda pior no caso de magic methods já que você acaba lidando com os atributos por [reflexão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex%C3%A3o_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)). Porém você vai ter que se esforçar muito para isso ter um efeito negativo palpável na sua aplicação, na esmagadora maioria dos casos você deveria estar mais preocupado com outras coisas como o cachear o acesso ao banco ao invés de ficar olhando em micro-otimizações de gettter/setter versus acesso direto ao atributo.

No fim só posso dizer que o uso é questão pessoal, você pode ter uma longa vida feliz como dev (dev+feliz=runtimeerror) sem nunca usar um getter/setter, mas sempre tem casos em que usar eles facilitaria a sua vida.

Comment: +1 pelo "um padrão que a maioria usa sem pensar nem contestar".