# Por qual motivo utilizar gets e sets em classes?

Tags: c++, classes

Qual é o motivo e quando realmente utilizar gets e sets em vez de uma variável publica em classes?

Dizem que é uma péssima pratica utilizar e modificar uma variável como publica, por que?

Exemplo 1:

```
class Teste
{
private;
    std::string nome;
public:
    std::string getNome() const { return this->nome };

    void setNome(std::string _nome) { this->nome = _nome; }
};

 Teste Teste;
 teste.setNome("Fulano");
 std::cout << "Nome: " << teste.getNome() << std::endl;
```

Exemplo 2:

```
class Teste
{
public:
   std::string nome;
};

Teste teste;
teste.nome = "Sicrano";
std::cout << teste.nome << std::endl;
```

Comment: Também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110785/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134750/101

Comment: Obrigado Maniero, a maioria é sobre outras linguagens mais tudo bem, acredito que se aplica ao C++ também e desculpe pela pergunta duplicada.

Comment: Sim, se aplica, vai seguindo os *links*. dentro delas, tem mais material ainda. Forme sua conclusão.