# Por que não devo alterar os "getter"s e "setter"s?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método, getters-setters

Recentemente me deparei com um amigo falando que não é aconselhável alterar *getter*s e *setter*s.

Eu havia feito a alteração de um setter de uma `List`. Nele eu não recebia uma lista por parâmetro, mas um objeto do tipo, e dentro do método eu fazia um `add` na lista, isso me poupou algumas linhas de código, porém fiquei em dúvida:

Será que vale tanto a pena investir em boas práticas de programação para detalhes tão pequenos que não farão diferença em desempenho ou em complexidade de código?

Comment: Talvez seja uma duplicada: [Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/3117)

Comment: @Math creio que não dupliquei, essa pergunta se refere a encapsulamento, minha duvida é saber se é um crime como dizem fazer uma alteração nos metodos assessores asuhsau

Comment: A justificativa para não alterar getters e setters é quando suas classes são usadas por terceiros (por exemplo, se elas fazem parte de uma biblioteca destinada a ser usada em outras aplicações). Você deve tomar cuidado para não quebrar a compatibilidade no código que faz uso dessa biblioteca. Fora isso não há mal nenhum em alterar getters e setters quando você constata que isso pode trazer benefício para seu código.

Comment: O comentário de @Piovezan responde perfeitamente e completamente a pergunta. Só mais um detalhe: um setter que adiciona o argumento em uma lista parece estranho. De repente este foi o motivo do questionamento do seu amigo. Não que este setter esteja necessariamente errado, de repente há um bom motivo, mas talvez valha a pena você questionar este ponto específico. Quanto a alterar um setter, é simplesmente o que foi dito por Piovezan; nada mais, nada menos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Primeiro, me parece que o exemplo citado nem é caso de usar um *setter* como ele costuma ser definido. Um *setter* é um método que recebe um valor que normalmente já iria em um campo, **eventualmente** faça algum processamento antes e/ou depois de atribuir para um campo privado que ele está encapsulando.

A descrição indica que esse é um método que pega um valor diferente e manipula um campo privado que tem outra função, ou seja, o acesso ao campo é indireto. Isso costuma ser recomendado sempre que faça sentido. Sempre que possível é melhor ter métodos que fazem algo mais específico do que um método que só serve para fazer uma atribuição.

Agora, todos os métodos públicos, ou mesmo campos que eventualmente sejam públicos fazem parte de um contrato que você definiu com que vá ser o consumidor desta classe. Você pode mexer quanto quiser em qualquer tipo de método, inclusive *getters* e *setters*, desde que não quebre esse contrato. Uma das coisas que não deve fazer é trocar a [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101). Mas nem precisa, basta criar um novo método com nova assinatura (mesmo que tenha o mesmo nome) que faça o que deseja agora e mantenha as duas versões. Se for o caso até anote esse método como obsoleto para evitar quem está usando que deve procurar a alternativa. Mas não apague algo que está disponibilizado publicamente.

Sempre deve fazer isso? Não. Se você puder garantir que não terá problemas, pode remover o que não é mais usado. Se a classe só é usada internamente você pode mexer em todo código que a consumiu, ou ainda se pode garantir que nada consumiu este método, mude. Você, procure os códigos afetados, faça o que tiver que fazer e seja feliz. Não dê atenção para quem fica pondo regra sem saber o seu caso real.

Se não quebrar contratos mude como quiser.

Mas note que eu não sei qual é o seu caso. Então não estou dizendo o que deve fazer. Estou só dando o subsídio para ter um pensamento crítico, saber onde dá problema e onde não dá, agora você analisa seu caso e tome uma decisão.

Algumas coisas que podem ajudar:

- [Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101)
- [Propriedade Vs variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101)
- [Por que é uma má prática ter atributos int?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/132272/101)
- [Quando usar Setters e Getters?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43757/101)
- [É realmente necessário usar métodos para mutator e acessor (setter e getter) no PHP? E o desempenho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110785/101)
- [Getters e Setters só podem "andar" juntos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44739/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Não há nada de errado em alterar o `get` e `set`. O `get` e `set` são apenas um padrão de nome adotado no Java para acessar as informações internas de um objeto.

Por exemplo, ao setar um `apelido` em uma classe `Pessoa`, você pode querer tratar espaços extras, validar se o apelido respeita o tamanho limite, etc dentro do `set` do apelido. Ou seja, você passa a responsabilidade para a própria classe tratar isto, o que é **perfeitamente válido** do ponto de vista de orientação à objetos.

Talvez exista dentro da aplicação na qual está trabalhando uma espécie uma **convenção** que `set` e `get` devam retornar exatamente o valor dos campos nos quais eles correspondem. Talvez esta classe que você alterou seja apenas para carregar dados de um lado ao outro. Enfim, em geral, este tipo de convenção com `get` e `set` é bem comum nos projetos, mas não existe nenhum problema em alterar o comportamento deles, depende mesmo do contexto na qual aquela classe encontra-se.

> Eu havia feito a alteração de um setter de uma List. Nele eu não
>   recebia uma lista por parâmetro, mas um objeto do tipo, e dentro do
>   método eu fazia um add na lista, isso me poupou algumas linhas de
>   código

Sua ideia faz todo sentido. Só me parece que chamar este método de `set` não foi a melhor decisão. Poderia ser um `adicionar` ou `add`, pois você não está definindo (*set*) uma lista para a classe, você está adicionando (*add*) um elemento na lista interna da classe. Inclusive, talvez o próprio método de `set` desta `List` nem deveria existir. Enfim, são só exemplos de como existem várias situações.