# TryParse do DateTime convertendo string no formato Double, como impedir isto?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho um método que usar o `DateTime.TryParse()` para converter uma *string* para o tipo `DateTime`, mas ultimamente percebi que *string* com o formato `Double` também estaria sendo convertido para data.

Existe alguma solução para corrigir isso?

```
public class SaidaData : SaidaBase
{
    public SaidaData() { }
    public DateTime? Data { get; set; }
}

public class SaidaBase
{
    public SaidaBase() { }

    public Boolean Sucesso { get; set; }
    public String Mensagem { get; set; }
}

public class EntradaBase
{
    public EntradaBase() { }

    public String Conteudo { get; set; }
    
}

public class Entrada : EntradaBase
{
    public Entrada() { }

    public Int32 PosIni { get; set; }
    public Int32 Tamanho { get; set; }
    public String[] Array { get; set; }
}

#region ConverterCampoDateTime
public static SaidaData ConverterCampoDateTime(Entrada entrada)
{
    var saida = new SaidaData();

    DateTime valor;
    var convertido = DateTime.TryParse(entrada.Conteudo, out valor);

    if (convertido)
    {
        //saida.Mensagem = Resources.Mensagens.OK;
        saida.Mensagem = "OK";
        saida.Sucesso = true;
        saida.Data = valor;
    }
    else
    {
        //saida.Mensagem = Resources.Mensagens.Erro;
        saida.Data = null;
        saida.Mensagem = "ERRO";
        saida.Sucesso = false;
    }

    return saida;
}
#endregion
```

[image: SS]
[image: SS]

Comment: Não entendi qual é o problema.

Comment: Quem manda na conversão **não é** o "formato" da string de entrada e sim a classe. Se você está usando `DateTime.TryParse` é óbvio que a conversão vai ser feita para uma data.

Comment: @bigown, o DateTime.TryParse recebe uma string ("276,11") e converte para uma data.

Comment: @jefersonb, não tem nenhuma forma para verificar isso?

Comment: Dá pra verificar na mão. Agora me explique uma coisa, você está passando este conteúdo para um método chamado `ConverterParaDateTime` e quer que a conversão não seja feita? Por que chamar o método então?

Comment: Esse método já existia na aplicação, e com ele também uma verificação se tinha sido convertido com sucesso e mostrado na classe conforme o código acima.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um método de *parse* analisa um texto e tenta achar algo que ele reconhece ali. Se ele reconhecer e puder gerar um resultado ele o fará. Ele faz o melhor esforço possível. Se a intenção é só reconhecer um formato específico tem que definir este formato, para isso existe o [`TryParseExact()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__). Exemplo (o formato, cultura e estilo pode ter que ser diferente):

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(entrada.Conteudo, "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var valor);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/TryParseExact.cs).

A confusão talvez ocorra porque os dados dessa classe são confusos. Talvez essas classes estejam suportando coisas demais.

Acho estranho ter essa herança, mas sei lá, não conheço o problema. Só estou dando uma dica que o problema pode ser maior e a arquitetura seja problemática, a conversão errada seja só o sintoma.

Se for para fazer uma classe assim, [tenho até minhas dúvidas se precisa de propriedades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134750/101).

[Esses construtores são desnecessários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Não gosto muito do uso dos tipos do .NET no lugar dos tipos do C#. É gosto, pode usar se quiser, mas é um indicativo de invencionice :)

A parte boa é que está usando um método `Try`.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, sua solução resolveu o problema, essa arquitetura realmente não é das boas, mas acredito que você já sabe como é trabalha em uma empresa com um sistema fortemente acoplado.

Comment: Sei sim como é ;)