# Verificar se uma data é valida

Tags: c#, string, validação, data

Estou recebendo uma data no formato: *string: "01/03/2010 23:00"*

Como eu conseguiria verificar se esta data é valida?

Por valida, desconsidere questões de dias ou meses estarem com números errados.
A validação seria só para ver se não existem letrar dentre os números e/ou símbolos que em lugares errados, como por exemplo: 0//03/2010 23::0

Existe alguma forma de eu fazer uma validação "integral" ou eu preciso separar os elementos da data e verifica-los um a um?

OBS.: Não posso utilizar as classes *DateTime e TimeSpan*.

Comment: Por que você não pode usar as classes DateTime? Isso é uma questão de prova, ou dever de casa de cursinho? A forma como você quer verificar a validade de uma data é muito ruim. O ideal é usar `DateTime.ParseExact()` e definir a forma da data. O que você está fazendo não é verificar se a data é inválida, já que vai aceitar `55/44/0001 34:68` como uma data válida... Embora a resposta de GOKU seja uma regexp que consegue, quase, pegar todos os cenários...

Comment: Porque não pode usar essas classes? Isso não faz o menor sentido. Se quer fazer algo errado precisaria de um justificativa.

Comment: Desde quando validar uma data sem usar uma forma "pronta" é errado? Não entendo pq criar o meu método de validação é errado... e, sim, é uma questão para meios educacionais.

Comment: @JonathanBarcela é bem complexo validar uma data, não basta olhar se tem os dígitos corretos ali, tem várias situações que vão dar resultado errado fazendo assim. Você pode aprender validar na mão, só que não do jeito errado. Se a sua pergunta fosse mais clara e não tivesse aceitado uma reposta bem ingênua eu entenderia que você quer aprender como é feito internamente, mas acabou ficando uma forma ruim e muita gente vai ler isso e achar que assim está bom e vai ter sistemas falhos. Dá uma olhada na complexidade:

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,f75289affb7e0ce3

Comment: @bigown, a reposta pode até ser ingênua, mas esta dentro do que ele esta estabelecendo.. Não posso utilizar as classes DateTime e TimeSpan.

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod o problema é a pergunta mesmo, não está ajudando ninguém e se não tivesse o alerta para as pessoas aqui muita gente iria copiar isso como se fosse algo válido. Pena que tem gente que não lerá os comentários e vai cometer o erro de tentar validar ingenuamente.

Comment: @bigown, não seja por isso. editado a resposta.

Comment: @JonathanBarcela, se fosse especificado _de cara_ de que trata-se de uma pergunta para fins educacionais, provavelmente toda essa discussão seria irrelevante. Acontece que utilizar de formas alternativas (e.g. regex) é errado em um sistema *produtivo* porque a forma "pronta" foi testada exaustivamente antes de ser liberada no framework.

Comment: (Nada contra sua resposta, @GOKUSSJGod ;) )

Comment: Na pergunta eu falo exatamente o que eu quero: `A validação seria só para ver se não existem letras dentre os números e/ou símbolos que em lugares errados, como por exemplo: 0//03/2010 23::0`. Eu não preciso de mais validações, isso pro meu caso, porém não achei uma forma melhor de descrever isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você não pode usar o `DateTime` uma saída seria o seguinte [regex](https://regex101.com/r/omEObf/1)  para fazer isso.

> ^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))/([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])/\d\d\d\d
>   [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]$

[Veja no dotnetfiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mM4Pk5)

Mas o ideal seria você utilizar o [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx), garantindo que você teria realmente uma data correta.

```
DateTime valor;
var convertido = DateTime
    .TryParseExact(entrada.Conteudo,
                    "dd/MM/yyyy",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None,
                    out valor);
```

Veja o ocorrido [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136014/erro-tryparse-do-datetime-convertendo-string-no-formato-double) para ter uma ideia.

Comment: Vlw :D Era isso mesmo que eu queria.

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que a data sempre é recebida no formato `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`, você pode usar a expressão `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}` para validar, veja um exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static bool validarData(string data)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2})");
        return r.Match(data).Success;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(validarData("01/03/2010 23:00"));
        Console.WriteLine(validarData("0//03/2010 23::0"));
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/05fXdC)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class ValidarData
{
    public static bool DataCompleta(string data)
    {
        Regex ok = new Regex(@"(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2})");
        return ok.Match(data).Success;
    }
    public static bool DataPura(string data)
    {
        Regex ok = new Regex(@"(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})");
        return ok.Match(data).Success;
    }
}
```

Para utilizar faça :

```
string Texto = "31/03/2021";
bool Dataok = ValidarData.DataPura(Texto);
```

ou

```
string Texto = "31/03/2021:14.30";
bool Dataok = ValidarData.DataCompleta(Texto);
```