# Validação e contagem de dias de uma data

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, validação

Considere uma data informada num formulário. Construa uma função que verifique se a data está correta (considerando ano bissexto, 31 de abril, etc). É preciso passar como parâmetro a data informada no formulário.

Se a data estiver correta, construa outra função que irá contar os dias do inicio do ano até a data informada. Novamente passando a data como parâmetro. Por exemplo, quantos dias tem 12/09/2015? Resposta 258.

O restante eu fiz, só não estou conseguindo fazer essa contagem dos dias.

Isso tudo está sendo feito em C# com Windows Forms:

```
    private void btnVerificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int iDia = Convert.ToInt32(txtDia.Text);
        int iMes = Convert.ToInt32(txtMes.Text);
        int iAno = Convert.ToInt32(txtAno.Text);
        VerificaAno(iAno);

        int iData = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year);
        VerificaData(iDia, iMes, iAno);


        int iTotalDias = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year);
        ContarDias(iDia, iMes, iAno, iData);

    }

    private void VerificaData(int iDia, int iMes, int iAno)
    {
        int iData = DateTime.DaysInMonth(iAno, iMes);

        if (iDia > iData || iDia < 1)
        {
            lblData.Text = "DATA INVÁLIDA";
            lblData.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            lblData.Text = "DATA VÁLIDA";
            lblData.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        }

    }

    private void ContarDias(int iDia, int iMes, int iAno, int iData)
    {
       #####NO CASO SERIA AQUI QUE EU IRIA FAZER O MEU CÓDIGO#####
    }


    private void VerificaAno(int iAno)
    {

        if (((iAno % 400) == 0) || (iAno % 4 == 0 && iAno % 100 != 0))
        {
            lblAnoBissexto.Text = "ANO BISSEXTO";
        }
        else
        {
            lblAnoBissexto.Text = "ANO NÃO BISSEXTO";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Está ocorrendo algum problema, ou qual o objetivo da pergunta? Se possível, deixar mais claro o que pretende fazer e melhorar a formatação da pergunta

Comment: A pergunta é antiga, mas um detalhe que não foi colocado nas respostas: para saber quantos dias se passaram desde o início do ano, pode usar `new DateTime(ano, mes, dia).DayOfYear`  -  a diferença é que `DayOfYear` também conta o dia 1 de janeiro. Já se calcular a diferença, como fizeram nas respostas, não conta (mas aí bastaria subtrair 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim como o Maniero disse subtraindo a data em questão com a data a começar do dia 1 do mesmo ano obtém um objeto do tipo [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) que representa a diferença de tempo entre duas datas. Essa diferença de tempo pode ser vista em várias unidades sendo uma delas em dias.

Exemplo de utilização no seu contexto:

```
private int ContarDias(int iDia, int iMes, int iAno)
{
    DateTime data = new DateTime(iAno, iMes, iDia); //data com ano mes e dia
    DateTime datadia1 = new DateTime(iAno, 1, 1); //data com ano, mes 1 e dia 1

    return (data - datadia1).Days; //devolver a diferença em dias
}
```

Repare que eu retirei o `iData` dos parâmetros pois não é necessário para o calculo que está a ser feito, assim como também troquei o tipo de retorno do método para `int` para que devolva apenas a quantidade de dias que passou.

Para utilizar de forma a mostrar numa Label como estava a fazer, precisa de chamar a função assim:

```
AlgumaLabel.Text = "Dias: " + ContarDias(iDia, iMes, iAno);
```

Se quiséssemos ser explícitos na diferença das datas poderia ser guardada a mesma no objeto `TimeSpan` correspondente, assim:

```
TimeSpan diferenca = (data - datadia1);
return diferenca.Days;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Isac.

Comment: Estou tentando utilizar o seu método é o que se parece mais com o que utilizo, porém ele está retornando erro ainda, será que poderia me dar uma ajuda. "Additional information: Os parâmetros Year, Month e Day descrevem um DateTime não representável."

Comment: @ThiagoSaracine Confirme que chama os parâmetros pela ordem correta, sendo esta `iDia`, `iMes`, `iAno`, assim como está em `ContarDias(iDia, iMes, iAno);`. Se inverter a ordem dos valores quando tentar criar a data, irá criar uma data com valores incorretos, e gerar o erro que indicou

Answer (score 3):

Vai algumas dicas:

A verificação de data pode ser simplificada assim:

```
try {
    var dataAtual = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(txtDia.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtMes.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtAno.Text));
    lblData.Text = "DATA VÁLIDA";
    lblData.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
} catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) {
    lblData.Text = "DATA INVÁLIDA";
    lblData.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Mas eu não sou fã, prefiro algo que crie uma *string* e faça um [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). Tem [exemplo para data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136014/101). Algo assim:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact($"{Convert.ToInt32(txtDia.Text)}/{ Convert.ToInt32(txtMes.Text)}/{Convert.ToInt32(txtAno.Text)}", "dd/MM/yyyy",
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dataAtual);
    lblData.Text = "DATA VÁLIDA";
    lblData.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
} else {
    lblData.Text = "DATA INVÁLIDA";
    lblData.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Estando com a data válida basta subtrair dela o dia primeiro de janeiro daquele ano e terá os dias sem maiores preocupações. Algo assim:

```
static int ContarDias(DateTime dataAtual) => (dataAtual - new DateTime(dataAtual.Year, 1, 1)).Days;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/DaysCount.cs).

- [Documentação `DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).
- [Documentação `TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Depois eu faço um teste.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer a contagem dos dias, você pode utilizar o `.TotalDays`, veja:

```
static int dias(DateTime data) //Pede uma data como parâmetro
{
    DateTime data2 = new DateTime(data.Year, 1, 1); //Cria uma data nova, com base no ano da variavel data
    return (int)(data - data2).TotalDays; //Retorna os dias. É preciso fazer o cast porque vem em double
}
```

Veja funcionando no [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n0hRKm).