# Saber quantas portas estão abertas em programa Java

Tags: java, classes

Estou com um programa em Java para saber quantas portas estão abertas mas não estou sabendo onde colocar o método para contar as portas. Posso criar um método contar as portas abertas dentro da classe `Porta`?

```
    package programa2;
    public class Programa2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Porta minhaPorta1;
    minhaPorta1 = new Porta();
    minhaPorta1.dimensaoX = 100;
    minhaPorta1.dimensaoY = 80;
    minhaPorta1.dimensaoZ = 30;
    minhaPorta1.cor = null;
    minhaPorta1.pinta("Verde");
    System.out.println("A porta é: " + minhaPorta1.cor + " e as dimensões são " + minhaPorta1.dimensaoX + ", " + minhaPorta1.dimensaoY + ", " + minhaPorta1.dimensaoZ + ".");
    minhaPorta1.abreFecha(1);

    Porta minhaPorta2;
    minhaPorta2 = new Porta();
    minhaPorta2.dimensaoX = 120;
    minhaPorta2.dimensaoY = 90;
    minhaPorta2.dimensaoZ = 40;
    minhaPorta2.cor = null;
    minhaPorta2.pinta("Azul");
    System.out.println("A porta é: " + minhaPorta2.cor + " e as dimensões são " + minhaPorta2.dimensaoX + ", " + minhaPorta2.dimensaoY + ", " + minhaPorta2.dimensaoZ + ".");
    minhaPorta2.abreFecha(2);

    Porta minhaPorta3;
    minhaPorta3 = new Porta();
    minhaPorta3.dimensaoX = 70;
    minhaPorta3.dimensaoY = 60;
    minhaPorta3.dimensaoZ = 10;
    minhaPorta3.cor = null;
    minhaPorta3.pinta("Amarela");
    System.out.println("A porta é: " + minhaPorta3.cor + " e as dimensões são " + minhaPorta3.dimensaoX + ", " + minhaPorta3.dimensaoY + ", " + minhaPorta3.dimensaoZ + ".");
    minhaPorta3.abreFecha(2);
}   
}
```

Classe Porta:

```
package programa2;
public class Porta {

boolean aberta;
String cor;
int dimensaoX, dimensaoY, dimensaoZ;

void abre() {
    this.aberta = true;
}

void fecha() {
    this.aberta = false;
}

void pinta(String novaCor) {
    this.cor = novaCor;
}

void abreFecha(int respUsuario) {
    switch (respUsuario) {
        case 1:
            abre();
            System.out.println("A porta está aberta.\n");
        break;
        case 2:
            fecha();
            System.out.println("A porta está fechada.\n");
        break;
    }
} 
}

int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas(){
    int cont = 0;
    if(this.minhaPorta1.abreFecha(1)){              
        cont = cont + 1;
    }
    if(this.minhaPorta2.abreFecha(1)){
        cont = cont + 1;
    }
    if(this.minhaPorta3.abreFecha(1)){
        cont= cont + 1;
    }           
    return cont; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Introdução

Você sempre pode fazer o que quiser. O ideal é que faça o melhor para cada situação. Quem está aprendendo ainda não sabe bem o que é melhor. Mas é certo que é mais vantajoso aprender em passos. Começar pelo simples, pelo que resolve. Não adianta aprender todos os conceitos possíveis e aplicar uma técnica válida sem sequer saber se essa técnica é necessária, ou porque está a usando. Pior, pode aprender o que se chama "boas práticas", ou seja, alguém te diz que o certo é tal coisa e você sai repetindo aquilo sem saber porque. E ocorre muito que em nome de fazer a "boa prática" muitas vezes se opta por um *design* mais complexo do que precisa de fato.

Isso é um exercício, o ideal é aprender todos conceitos corretamente, nas não precisa aprender conceitos que não são absolutamente necessários para esse problema. Principalmente não precisa aprender conceitos que não são unânimes.

## Contar as portas abertas

A classe `Porta` só deveria cuidar de uma porta. Mas nada impede que nela se controle alguns aspectos gerais de todas as portas existentes. Novamente, se isso é o erro ou não para o problema ainda não sabe, e fica difícil saber já que o problema não é real, é só para treinar alguns aspectos.

O jeito mais fácil de resolver é ter uma variável de classe (em oposição à uma variável de instância que pertence à cada objeto `porta`), assim há um só dado para toda aplicação. Nessa variável vai controlando quantas estão abertas. Obviamente que deve-se somar e subtrair sempre que manda abrir e fechar a porta.

Pode-se criar um método para acessar essa variável, como foi feito no exemplo. Mas como ele vai acessar uma variável estática (de classe) o método pode ser estático também.

## Organizando o código

Aproveitando vamos melhorar algumas coisas que já cabem mesmo em aprendizado de coisa simples. Acostume-se organizar bem o código. Esse está acima da média de iniciantes, mas algumas coisas podem ser melhoradas.

Acostume-se dizer a visibilidade de todos os membros mesmo que não seja necessário. Diga o que é público e o que é privado, isso documenta melhor. Especialmente torne a variável `aberta` privada. O ideal (mas não deve ser seguido sempre) é que todas variáveis sejam privadas. Esta em especial não tem porque ficar pública já que ela não é acessada publicamente.

Muitas pessoas vão dizer para criar métodos acessadores públicos `get` e `set` para todas variáveis e torne-as privadas. [Depende, isso pode ser bom ou não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134760/101). Saiba que pode fazer isso, mas entenda primeiro porque fazer antes de começar aplicar.

Os dados das dimensões da porta parecem ser obrigatórios, não? Ou seja, se eles não existirem, a porta não existe. Se for isso considere [criar um construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) para enviar esses dados e só assim a porta pode ser criada.

## Pequenos problemas

Eu retirei as linhas que colocavam a `cor` como `null`. A criação da classe já garante isso, é redundância.

No `switch` chamava o método `abre()` nas duas situações, acho que isso foi um lapso. Consertei.

Tirei o `this` já que ele é redundante, nem todo mundo gosta disto.

Tenho minhas dúvidas se mandar um número para um método abrir e escolher o que fazer é uma boa ideia. Não parece ser responsabilidade da classe `Porta` cuidar disso, este método não parece ser adequado aí, mas para um exercício inicial está bom assim.

O dia que achar que precisa de uma solução mais robusta, que usará concorrência, se tiver determinado porque precisa saber quantas portas estão abertas, se outras informações gerais sobre as portas serão necessárias, se elas estarão associadas à alguma coisa (um imóvel, por exemplo), ou seja, quando tiver um problema melhor definido, poderá fazer um *design* mais complexo com outras classes adequadas para o problema. Sem a definição adequada dos requisitos criará soluções *frankestein*, isso é criar vício.

## Conclusão

Obviamente outras melhorias podem ser feitas, mas acho que já ajudou bastante.

Em um problema real terá que pensar em outras coisas, essa implementação é bem ingênua.

Mas eu ficaria longe de *designs* complexos por enquanto. Tente fazer a classe sozinha funcionar bem. Quando dominar bem isso, aí poderá pensar em arquitetura. Idealmente com problemas reais.

```
class Porta {
    private static int portasAbertas = 0;
    private boolean aberta;
    public String cor;
    public int dimensaoX, dimensaoY, dimensaoZ;
    
    public void abre() {
        if (!aberta) {
            portasAbertas++;
            aberta = true;
        }
    }
    
    public void fecha() {
       if (aberta) {
            portasAbertas--;
           aberta = false;
       }
    }
    
    public void pinta(String novaCor) {
        cor = novaCor;
    }
    
    public void abreFecha(int respUsuario) {
        switch (respUsuario) {
            case 1:
                abre();
                System.out.println("A porta está aberta.\n");
            break;
            case 2:
                fecha();
                System.out.println("A porta está fechada.\n");
            break;
        }
    } 
    
    public static int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() {
        return portasAbertas; 
    }
}

class Programa2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Porta minhaPorta1;
        minhaPorta1 = new Porta();
        minhaPorta1.dimensaoX = 100;
        minhaPorta1.dimensaoY = 80;
        minhaPorta1.dimensaoZ = 30;
        minhaPorta1.pinta("Verde");
        System.out.println("A porta é: " + minhaPorta1.cor + " e as dimensões são " + minhaPorta1.dimensaoX + ", " + minhaPorta1.dimensaoY + ", " + minhaPorta1.dimensaoZ + ".");
        minhaPorta1.abreFecha(1);
    
        Porta minhaPorta2;
        minhaPorta2 = new Porta();
        minhaPorta2.dimensaoX = 120;
        minhaPorta2.dimensaoY = 90;
        minhaPorta2.dimensaoZ = 40;
        minhaPorta2.pinta("Azul");
        System.out.println("A porta é: " + minhaPorta2.cor + " e as dimensões são " + minhaPorta2.dimensaoX + ", " + minhaPorta2.dimensaoY + ", " + minhaPorta2.dimensaoZ + ".");
        minhaPorta2.abreFecha(2);
    
        Porta minhaPorta3;
        minhaPorta3 = new Porta();
        minhaPorta3.dimensaoX = 70;
        minhaPorta3.dimensaoY = 60;
        minhaPorta3.dimensaoZ = 10;
        minhaPorta3.pinta("Amarela");
        System.out.println("A porta é: " + minhaPorta3.cor + " e as dimensões são " + minhaPorta3.dimensaoX + ", " + minhaPorta3.dimensaoY + ", " + minhaPorta3.dimensaoZ + ".");
        minhaPorta3.abreFecha(2);
        
        System.out.println(Porta.quantasPortasEstaoAbertas());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iJcPAy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hgeolfud-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Gates.java).

Comment: Nossa, perfeito! Sei um básico de PHP e comecei a duas semanas estudar java e orientação a objetos por uma apostila. Vou observar as dicas que deu e ir melhorando. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

O melhor lugar para este método não é dentro da classe `Porta`, já que, para isso, você precisaria passar uma lista das portas instanciadas para que a contagem seja feita. Note que, idealmente, uma instância da classe porta deveria saber somente sobre ela.

Nesse caso, uma alternativa é fazer essa contagem numa classe que se chama `PortaManager`. Essa classe teria a lista de portas instanciadas em sua aplicação. Um método percorreria essa lista para retornar a quantidade de portas que estão abertas.

Veja o código abaixo. A única mudança na classe Main é que as portas precisam ser adicionadas na PortaManager.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PortaManager portaManager = new PortaManager();

        Porta minhaPorta1;
        minhaPorta1 = new Porta();
        minhaPorta1.dimensaoX = 100;
        minhaPorta1.dimensaoY = 80;
        minhaPorta1.dimensaoZ = 30;
        minhaPorta1.cor = null;
        minhaPorta1.pinta("Verde");
        System.out.println("A porta é: " + minhaPorta1.cor + " e as dimensões são " + minhaPorta1.dimensaoX + ", " + minhaPorta1.dimensaoY + ", " + minhaPorta1.dimensaoZ + ".");
        minhaPorta1.abreFecha(1);
        portaManager.adicionar(minhaPorta1);


        Porta minhaPorta2;
        minhaPorta2 = new Porta();
        minhaPorta2.dimensaoX = 120;
        minhaPorta2.dimensaoY = 90;
        minhaPorta2.dimensaoZ = 40;
        minhaPorta2.cor = null;
        minhaPorta2.pinta("Azul");
        System.out.println("A porta é: " + minhaPorta2.cor + " e as dimensões são " + minhaPorta2.dimensaoX + ", " + minhaPorta2.dimensaoY + ", " + minhaPorta2.dimensaoZ + ".");
        minhaPorta2.abreFecha(2);
        portaManager.adicionar(minhaPorta2);

        Porta minhaPorta3;
        minhaPorta3 = new Porta();
        minhaPorta3.dimensaoX = 70;
        minhaPorta3.dimensaoY = 60;
        minhaPorta3.dimensaoZ = 10;
        minhaPorta3.cor = null;
        minhaPorta3.pinta("Amarela");
        System.out.println("A porta é: " + minhaPorta3.cor + " e as dimensões são " + minhaPorta3.dimensaoX + ", " + minhaPorta3.dimensaoY + ", " + minhaPorta3.dimensaoZ + ".");
        minhaPorta3.abreFecha(2);
        portaManager.adicionar(minhaPorta3);

        System.out.println("A quantidade de portas abertas é: " + portaManager.quantasPortasEstaoAbertas());
    }
}
```

Veja a classe PortaManager abaixo. Ela pode ser melhorada, incluindo métodos para excluir portas, etc.

```
class PortaManager {
    private List<Porta> portas;

    PortaManager() {
        portas = new ArrayList<Porta>();
    }

    public int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() {
        int resultado = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < portas.size();i++) {
            if (portas.get(i).aberta)
                resultado++;
        }

        return resultado;
    }

    public void adicionar(Porta porta) {
        portas.add(porta);
    }
}
```

Comment: O certo seria colocar o método quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() em uma outra classe?

Comment: Minha proposta é exatamente essa, mas para isso, você precisa saber trabalhar com listas em Java. Cada porta instanciada, seria adicionada na classe PortaManager (que terá uma lista de portas instanciadas). Essa mesma classe, teria o método quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() que percorreria a lista interna na PortaManager e retornaria quantas estão abertas.

Comment: Estou começando a estudar java agora e não sei ainda como trabalhar com listas ou arrays. Sem isso fica impossível fazer com o que tem no código atualmente?

Comment: Não fica impossível, mas eu não iria por esse caminho, pois ele não vai te agregar muito, pode até mesmo criar vícios desnecessários em seu estilo de programar. Arrays são estruturas básicas de programação, portanto, aprendê-los é fundamental. Note que o problema do método quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() que você escreveu é que ele funciona somente para 3 portas e as mesmas precisam chamar minhaPorta1,minhaPorta2,minhaPorta3.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou implementar a sua solução em outro exemplo para usar a melhor forma em cada caso.