# Como evitar o uso de setters em casos desse tipo?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, modelagem, ddd, getters-setters

Na orientação a objetos em geral o recomendável é evitar o uso de setters. A justificativa usual para isso é que a lógica que modifica o estado de um objeto deve estar encapsulada no objeto. Logo, o ideal é o objeto expor comportamentos, e esses comportamentos terem como efeito colateral sua modificação de estado.

O exemplo tradicional é uma classe representando uma conta bancária. Ao invés de usarmos um setter para modificar o saldo, o saldo é modificado como efeito colateral de operações como transferências. Seria algo como

```
public class ContaBancaria
{
    public Saldo { get; private set; }

    public bool Transfere(decimal valor, ContaBancaria conta)
    {
        // Logica de transferencia
    }
}
```

Acontece que em alguns casos é fácil identificar a modificação de estado como efeito colateral de um comportamento do objeto. No caso da conta, o saldo é modificado quando operações bancárias são realizadas. No caso de um produto que tem sua quantidade controlada no estoque, a quantidade seria modificada em processos de compra e venda, etc.

O problema é que tem situações que é realmente complicado identificar a modificação de estado dessa forma.

Alguns exemplos: uma classe que modela um cliente, uma classe que modela um usuário, uma classe que modela uma empresa.

Em geral essas classes *fazem parte do domínio*. São conceitos do espaço do problema, são termos da linguagem ubíqua e são necessários para as operações do domínio. Mais do que isso, em geral essas classes tem várias propriedades.

Por exemplo: um cliente tem um nome, tem um CPF, tem um endereço de e-mail associado, tem um telefone, um endereço, etc.

E isso me confunde. Porque é necessário expor funcionalidades para modificar esse estado: mudar o nome, o CPF, o e-mail, o telefone, o endereço, etc.

O problema é: qual o comportamento responsável por essas mudanças? Eu penso muito e não tem. Ao tentar dar um nome ao método que muda o nome por exemplo, eu não tenho a menor ideia do que seria.

Se eu for por esse lado, vou acabar criando um método `ModificaNome`, mas isso é totalmente equivalente a um setter.

Nesses casos, em que não conseguimos identificar a princípio um comportamento responsável pela mudança de estado de um conjunto de propriedades, como conseguimos evitar o uso de setters e obter um bom design orientado a objetos?

Comment: A pergunta parte de uma premissa errada. Você simplesmente não tem que evitar o uso de setters. Use setters sempre que precisar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O bom *design* orientado a objeto resolve problemas da melhor forma possível. Quando ele é usado pra atender regras sem sentido, não é bom *design*. Se alguém lhe disse que precisa fazer isso, melhor rever suas influências (o que é um direito seu escolhê-las, até porque quem terá que arcar com as consequências é você mesmo).

Como uma nota lateral talvez isso se deva por obsessão por uma metodologia que diz algo ideológico.

Faça o *setter* e pronto. Tem coisa que é a modificação do estado pura e simples, não tem o que inventar. Ou [nem faça o *setter* se ele realmente não for necessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101). E [nem sempre é](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134750/101). Isso parece uma heresia para alguns, mas é uma solução válida quando se sabe o que está fazendo. Os *links* mostram um pouco mais quando evitar. Mesmo que não queira optar por isso porque quem sabe, talvez, um dia, quiçá, precisará dele e "o DDD me disse que tem que fazer", então use-o.

Não sei se o DDD diz para evitar o *setter*, se o faz é só um motivo a mais para deixar a metodologia de lado. Remédios lhe ajudam, drogas te consomem. Eu até concordo que se é natural evitá-lo, faça, mas não deixe artificialismos determinar seu caminho.

Tem metodologia que é uma coleção de boas práticas que, como mostra essa pergunta, trazem mais problemas do que soluções. A única boa prática é fazer o certo em cada situação. Ou aceita esse fato genérico para te guiar, ou analisa o caso concreto para obter uma resposta do que precisa. Tentar achar respostas concretas padrões em casos abstratos não costuma funcionar, porque gera a tal da boa prática.

Então no caso mais ou menos concreto apresentado na pergunta, qual o problema de ter uma **propriedade** `Nome` do `Cliente` que não faça algo de especial? Se não conseguir responder esta pergunta de forma definitiva e simples, está procurando chifre em cabeça de cavalo. Por outro lado, se puder fazer a mudança dos dados de outra forma, pode ser interessante, pode dar mais semântica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Ótima maturidade na sua interpretação. O que você está percebendo é que, um entidade oblíqua tem sua visão modificada por quem a está olhando. Pegando o exemplo de uma **Pessoa**:

- O governo te enxerga como RG, CPF, Estado Civil, etc;
- Seus pais te enxergam como Olhos do Pai, Sorriso da Mãe, Timbre de Voz, etc;
- O medico te enxerga como Sexo, Peso, Altura, Colesterol, etc;
- O carteiro te enxerga como Nome, CEP, Número, etc;

Isso quer dizer que, uma mesma entidade muda para cara **contexto**.

Em arquitetura de software, esse *pattern* chama-se [Bounded Context ou Contextos Delimitados](http://eduardopires.net.br/2016/03/ddd-bounded-context/).

Essa postura atende esse "incômodo" que você está sentindo. Sua solução completa pode, e deve, possuir micro-módulos/serviços - totalmente isolados, inclusive. No módulo de cadastro de pessoas, tem-se a entidade *Pessoa* com nome, data de nascimento, telefones, enfim, informações pertinentes ao contexto de cadastro de pessoas.

E em outro módulo, bancário, tem-se a entidade *Correntista*, onde possui agencia, conta, imagem da assinatura, etc. Neste módulo, sua entidade possui *setters* para manipular dados bancários, mas nenhum para manipular cadastro de pessoas. E vice-versa.

Concluindo, veja sobre Contextos Delimitados que irá atender essa necessidade que você já está sentindo, e faz todo sentindo em desenvolvimento de software de maneira responsável.

Answer (score 6):

Leonardo, a sua pergunta é boa e uma parte em específico me chamou atenção:

> O problema é: qual o comportamento responsável por essas mudanças?

Perceba que as vezes a alteração de uma simples informação é um grande comportamento em si próprio. Quem vai dizer se é ou não é será você mesmo que é o especialista no negócio.

Já que você citou o CPF como exemplo, qual seria o processo existente no seu negócio para troca de CPF?

- É necessário verificar se já existe algum outro cliente usando esse CPF?
- É requerido que este CPF não esteja na lista de maus pagadores?
- Precisa garantir que o CPF bate com o nome que foi informado?

Perceba que se pelo menos uma validação for necessária podemos dizer que **mudar um CPF** é algo perigoso e que envolve complexidade, tornando-se um comportamento esperado do seu sistema. Para lidar com essa complexidade removemos o settler para encapsular a mudança. Queremos garantir que essa troca CPF não irá gerar um estado inválido. Perceba que não tem ideologia nenhuma aqui. Apenas boas práticas.

De todos os exemplos que você deu de atributos (nome, CPF, endereço, email, telefone) muito provavelmente, em qualquer sistema um pouquinho mais complexo, seriam considerados ValueObjects devido a imutabilidade.

Entretanto...

Se trocar o CPF não significa nada demais em seu projeto sendo apenas uma atribuição de valores simples, logo você não tem complexidade envolvida. Se você não tem complexidade envolvida, você não precisa de ferramentas/processos/técnicas para lidar com a tal da complexidade. Logo, DDD (ou qualquer outra coisa para lidar com complexidade) seria Overengineering