# Diferença de Set e Get em programação orientada a objeto

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, getters-setters

Qual é a diferença básica de `set` e `get` em programação orientada a objeto?

Comment: Pode detalhar mais o que deseja saber? Alguma aqui não é o que deseja? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getters-setters?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que deseja saber sobre uma propriedade ou um método de prefixo `set` e `get`, este padrão é usado para abstrair um estado que dever ser interno ao objeto. Eles são usados como [facilitadores em casos de campos que deve ser acessados de forma simples e direta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33723/101) para **pegar o valor de um atributo (`get`)** ou para **alterar o valor deste atributo (`set`)**.

Eles [são chamados também de *acessadores* e *mudadores*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110785/101).

Em geral fala-se que eles causam uma [ilusão de encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101), porque encapsular de verdade é [criar métodos que fazem algo especial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143099/101) que não encapsula apenas o acesso ou atribuição, é criar um significado para o método. Ele é uma abstração mas não um encapsulamento.

Eles são usados para esconder o detalhe de como o estado é armazenado e/ou calculado, validado, etc. Esconder o detalhe é uma abstração.

Há uma corrente que diz que eles devem ser usados sempre, mesmo que não faça nenhum processamento adicional além de pegar o valor (`get`) ou atribuir o valor (`ser`) à variável da classe. Assim se um dia precisar colocar algo basta muda a implementação deste par de métodos e todo mundo que consome o objeto passa usar da nova forma. Isto é uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Mas há quem é mais pragmático e só usa quando necessário, até porque em geral é fácil refatorar.

Há ainda quem diz que eles sempre são um erro porque os métodos deveriam ter uma função própria, apenas deixar pegar ou alterar o dado de um campo é expor detalhe disfarçadamente.

Algumas linguagens possuem facilidades para que esse par de métodos pareça uma variável simples, [é o caso do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101). Pode ser visto como é [diferente em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149348/101).

Eles podem ser usados separadamente. De fato é comum ter um `get` e não um `set`. Em alguns caso o `set` fica privado ou protegido para só o próprio objeto poder acessá-lo.

Veja [argumentos para usar em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40416/101).

Há uma [explicação quando usar em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43757/101).

Veja [como é usado em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186982/101).

Exemplo em pseudocódigo:

```
class Cliente { //exemplo bem meia boa
    private string nome; //note que é privado
    public string getNome() => return nome; //aqui pega a variável interna e retorna
    public void setNome(string nome) => this.nome = nome; //aqui joga o parâmetro na variável da classe
    private decimal saldo;
    public decimal getSaldo() => return saldo - 100; //dá uma margem de erro
    public void setSaldo(decimal valor) => if (valor > 200) saldo = valor; //só aceita um mínimo de 200
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/GetterSetter.cs).

Answer (score 3):

O método  `(GET)`  serve para recuperar um dado e o método `(SET)` serve para modificar um dado

Na verdade, existem muitas boas razões para considerar o uso de métodos (getters e setters) em vez de expor diretamente campos de uma classe - além do argumento de encapsulamento e facilitando as futuras mudanças.

Aqui estão algumas das razões:

- Encapsulamento do comportamento associado à obtenção ou configuração
  da propriedade - isso permite que a funcionalidade adicional (como a
  validação) seja adicionada com mais facilidade mais tarde.
- Ocultando a representação interna da propriedade ao expor uma propriedade usando uma representação alternativa.
- Isolando sua interface pública da mudança - permitindo que a
  interface pública permaneça constante enquanto a implementação muda
  sem afetar os consumidores existentes.
- Controlando a semântica de gerenciamento de vida e memória
  (eliminação) da propriedade - particularmente importante em ambientes
  de memória não gerenciados (como C ++ ou Objective-C).
- Fornecer um ponto de interceptação de depuração para quando uma propriedade muda no tempo de execução - a depuração quando e onde uma propriedade alterada para um valor específico pode ser bastante difícil sem isso em algumas linguagens.
- Permitir que os herdeiros alterem a semântica de como a propriedade se comporta e é exposta, substituindo os métodos getter / setter.
- Getters e setters podem permitir diferentes níveis de acesso - por exemplo, o get pode ser público, mas o conjunto pode ser protegido.

Comment: Era isto que procurava ?

Comment: Isso mesmo.. Obrigado