# Classe com método para alterar um parâmetro

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, classes

Tenho uma classe Usuário com atributos privados como `Nome`, `Endereco` e `Telefone`. Essa classe possui um método construtor que recebe parâmetros como `nome`, `endereco` e `telefone`.

Eu gostaria de usar um método construtor para alterar o parâmetro telefone. Ou seja, para alterar o dado (número de telefone) que a pessoa inseriu na textbox.

Tudo isso é numa *Windows Forms Application* em C#.

Gostaria de saber como alterar esse dado e levando em conta que o exercício proposto que eu recebi só aceita o uso de linguagem C# orientada a objetos mesmo (estou começando a aprender sobre e é para depois aprender sobre toda a parte de SQL e tudo mais, agora é só o básico sem entrar em ADO.NET ou ASP.NET).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Usuario
{
    public string Nome {get; private set;}
    public string Endereco {get; private set;}
    public string Telefone {get; private set;}

    public Usuario()
    {

    }

    public Usuario(string nome, string endereco, string telefone)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Endereco = endereco;
        Telefone = telefone;
    }

    public void AlterarNome(string novoNome)    
    {
        Nome = novoNome;
    }

    public void AlterarEndereco(string novoEndereco)
    {
        Endereco = novoEndereco;
    }

    public void AlterarTelefone(string novoTelefone)
    {
        Telefone = novoTelefone;
    }
}

//win form
var usuario = new Usuario();
usuario.AlterarNome(this.txtNome.Text);
```

Comment: E se eu quiser colocar um Button para alterar todas as informações dos TextBox ao mesmo tempo, como eu faço? Eu tenho que chamar esses AlterarNome(), AlterarEndereco() lá no form1.cs?

Answer (score 2):

Em C# [o que você chama de atributo na verdade é chamado de campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/101) ([confusão de termos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101)). Em C# [não se usa métodos para encapsular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101) os campos, [usa-se propriedades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101), que na verdade são [métodos disfarçados que acessam um campo privado implícito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134750/101).

Claro que não vou fazer uma classe completa com validação, e outros componentes, mas basicamente deve ter um construtor, como o enunciado pede e as propriedades. Mais nada é necessário para o básico.

O uso no Winforms depende do que está fazendo, como não tem exemplo na pergunta, comentei como pode ser uma possibilidade.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var usuario = new Usuario("João", "Rua da avenida, 123", "1234-5678");
        usuario.Telefone = "9876-5432";
        //No Winforms seria algo como
        //usuario.Telefone = Formulario.Telefone.Text
    }
}

public class Usuario {
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public string Endereco {get; set;}
    public string Telefone {get; set;}

    public Usuario(string nome, string endereco, string telefone) {
        Nome = nome;
        Endereco = endereco;
        Telefone = telefone;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0Z6h8W). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YtEAXj). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/PropertyChange.cs).

Comment: E se eu quiser colocar um Button para alterar todas as informações dos TextBox ao mesmo tempo (no caso, só vai alterar o que o usuário selecionar com o cursor na textbox para alterar mudando o que está escrito), como eu faço? Eu tenho que chamar, por exemplo, AlterarNome() e AlterarEndereco() lá no form1.cs? Não sei se deu para entender direito o que eu tô pedindo,qualquer coisa eu mando algum print da tela que eu tô pensando

Comment: @beginner Isso é outra pergunta de ouro assunto, se esta já foi respondida pode aceitar a que foi mais útil para você. Mais pra frente poderá votar em tudo que achar útil no site. Se não sabe como aceitar veja o [tour].