# Por que usar getters e setters nas classes?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, getters-setters

Por que eu preciso encapsular toda a classe, se, eu como programador, sei perfeitamente como usar aquela variável. Só vejo necessidade de setters e getters que trabalham o valor da variável, assim:

```
void setCommand (string val)
{
    string ret = "";

    for (char it : val)
        ret += toupper(it);
    command = ret;
}
```

Mas qual a necessidade de usar setters ou getters como esse:

```
void setMoney (float val)
{
    money = val;
}
float getMoney ()
{
    return money;
}
```

Comment: Ainda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44739/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40416/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129353/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204355/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45285/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202227/101 e tem uma penca de relacionadas que nem vou postar aqui.

Comment: Só tem esse que já respondem isto. Não precisava nem de um pesquisa, na hora que estava digitando apareceu todas elas.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente isso é um dos conceitos da orientação a objeto, o encapsulamento, na qual vc pode definir a sua variável como privado, e criar o getter e setter para poder acessar ela a partir de outra classe

ex:

```
class Pessoa {
  String nome;
  public String getNome() {
    return this.nome;
  }
  public void setNome(String s) {
    this.nome = s;
  } 
}
```

Classe main

```
class main() {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
    pessoa.setNome("João");
    System.out.println(pessoa.getNome());
  }
}
```

Nessa situação eu criei a classe Pessoa e definir dentro dela uma variável privada do tipo String chamada nome, na qual eu quero acessar ela fora da classe Pessoa, para isso eu criei o setter e o getter da var pessoa, tornando possível acessar a mesma em outras classes

No ex que eu dei, eu acessei ela a partir da classe main, criei um objeto do tipo Pessoa, e definir um nome a ele "João" a partir do método `setNome()` da classe Pessoa, dps exibi um nome que eu passei a mesma na tela através do metodo `getNome()`

Comment: Na verdade isso é um engano comum. Não há nada em OOP que diz que devem existir *getters*  e *setters*. O encapsulamento é algo mais amplo e conceitual que isto (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96656/101). E a pergunta era sobre porque e não como funciona já que a pergunta implica que isto já é sabido. O mais importante de tudo isso é que a maioria das pessoas criam esse par de métodos achando que estão fazendo OOP quando na verdade OOP tem filosofia contrária. è para criar métodos que fazem alguma coisa útil e não apenas um anteparo para os campos.

Comment: É como eu disse outro dia, OOP é como sexo de adolescente, todo mundo fala que faz, mas fazer mesmo poucos fazem. Primeiro precisa entender o que é OOP para poder fazer certo. A maioria acha que sabe porque vão seguindo as receitas de bolo espalhadas por aí. Existe motivos para usar esses métodos, mas conceitualmente OOP prega algo mais abstrato no encapsulamento, *getters* e *setters são concretos demais. E muitas vezes é pra quebrar tudo isso.

Comment: Pelo oq o meu professor me ensinou, o método setter e getter são usado para que não tenhamos acesso diretamente a variável, podendo causar assim danos ao sistema quando n acessado corretamente, por nos mesmos, ou por outros programadores

Comment: É o que eu falei, as pessoas seguem cegamente regrinhas sem entender o real motivo do mecanismo. E não causa danos à sistema algum. Ou seja, sem entender o real motivo deles existirem ninguém vai usar certo. Sem usar certo é melhor nem usar. E por terem aprendido errado, ensinam errado e aí cria-se um círculo vicioso onde todo mundo acha que aprendeu certo. É o mesmo que acontece com comentários onde quase todos professores falam para usar e abusar deles, quando é o contrário. Fazia sentidos nos anos 50/60, estava nos livros, deixou de fazer sentido, mas continuam ensinando isso.

Comment: Tudo isso porque as pessoas aprendem as regras e não o porquê delas existirem. A pergunta, apesar de duplicata, é muito boa porque pede o Porquê, o que é o melhor que deve se aprender. Assim se entende quando usar ou não. Eu sou um enorme crítico das boas práticas, porque estregam a cabeça das pessoas. Elas ensinam e regra e não o motivador da regra (salvo exceções, mas aí não precisa mais chamar de boa prática), e as pessoas conhecem o mecanismo e não quando usar ou não usar, como aplicar. Pesquisa aí: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+boa+pr%C3%A1tica